# Can i store a Map<String, Object> inside a Shared Preferences in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way that we could save a map object into shared preferences so that we can fetch the data from shared preferences rather than listening to the database all the time.
actually i want to reduce the amount of data downloaded from firebase. so i am thinking of a solution to have a listener for shared prefs and read the data from shared prefs.

But i dont see a way of achieving this in flutter or dart.

Please can someone help me to achieve this if there is a workaround.

Many Thanks,
Mahi

Answer (score 98, accepted):

If you convert it to a string, you can store it

```
import 'dart:convert';
...
var s = json.encode(myMap);
// or var s = jsonEncode(myMap);
```

`json.decode(...)`/`jsonDecode(...)` makes a map from a string when you load it.

Comment: this is amazing thanks very much @GunterZochbauer ,this works perfectly.

Comment: That is exactly the solution I use myself too, nice ;)

Comment: Can I save a List<Object> in the Shared Preference?

Comment: No, only JSON. You need to encode it first. Shared Preferences is storage outside your application and only serialized data can be stored outside an app in general, not just plain objects.

Comment: Not able to convert into string

Answer (score 2):

Might be easier with this package:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pref_dessert

Look at the example:

```
import 'package:pref_dessert/pref_dessert.dart';

/// Person class that you want to serialize:
class Person {
  String name;
  int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);
}

/// PersonDesSer which extends DesSer<T> and implements two methods which serialize this objects using CSV format:
class PersonDesSer extends DesSer<Person>{
  @override
  Person deserialize(String s) {
    var split = s.split(",");
    return new Person(split[0], int.parse(split[1]));
  }

  @override
  String serialize(Person t) {
    return "${t.name},${t.age}";
  }

}

void main() {
  var repo = new FuturePreferencesRepository<Person>(new PersonDesSer());
  repo.save(new Person("Foo", 42));
  repo.save(new Person("Bar", 1));
  var list = repo.findAll();

}
```

Package is still under development so it might change, but any improvements and ideas are welcomed! :)

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't like to convert String to JSON or vice versa, personally recommend [localstorage](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage), this is the easiest way I had ever found to store any `data<T>` in Flutter.

```
import 'package:localstorage/localstorage.dart';

final LocalStorage store = new LocalStorage('myapp');

...

setLocalStorage() async {
  await store.ready;       // Make sure store is ready
  store.setItem('myMap', myMapData);
}

...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: and how exactly you are getting that one? with getItem?

Answer (score 1):

In dart's `Shared Preferences` there is no way to store Map directly but you can easily trick this by, converting `Map` to `String` then save it as usual, and when you need it to retrieve the String and then convert it back to `Map`. So simple!

**Convert your map into `String` using `json.encode()` and then save it,**

When you need your map use `json.decode()` to get back your map from the string.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

final yourStr = sharedPreferences.getString("yourkey");
var map = json.decode(yourStr);

sharedPreferences.setString("yourkey", json.encode("value"));
```