# Is there any solution to store and retrieve list of object from shared preferences?

Tags: list, object, flutter, sharedpreferences

I want to store a list of objects into shared preferences, then get back the list from it.

I have tried to store a list of objects but I'm getting an error like cannot 
 encoding the object.

```
 var list = jsonEncode(Building.getInstance().childList.toString());
 pref.putString(SharedKey().CHILD_LIST,list);
```

I expected to get the list of objects as I have stored in shared preferences.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116773/can-i-store-a-mapstring-object-inside-a-shared-preferences-in-dart

Comment: or https://pub.dev/packages/pref_dessert

Comment: I am expecting to store list of object in shared preferences not map

Comment: There is no such way to directly store objects. There is a technical reason for that. Btw, pref_dessert stores it as Map<String,Object>

Comment: Yes. I am storing list as a string and then retrieving as a string it self by decoding but not able to get original list of object, can you please help me.

Comment: @Mohit Shetty I am retrieving stored list as a string only, is there any operation to do on stored list to get list of object my original list

Comment: You might want to check this one https://github.com/leisim/hive/blob/master/hive/README.md?source=post_page-----d90cedf6fd25----------------------#read--write

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your complex object list to json string and save with setStringList 
And use getStringList to get json string and convert it back to your complex object list

full code demo use setStringList and getStringList

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _save,
          child: new Text('Save my list of int'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_save() async {
  List<String> myListOfStrings=  ["1","2","3","4"];

  List<String> myListOfJsonStrings=  ['{ "storeid":"123",  "storename":"jock"}',' {  "storeid":"456",  "storename":"abc"}' ];

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setStringList('mylist', myListOfStrings);

  List<String> myList = (prefs.getStringList('mylist') ?? List<String>()) ;
  print('Your list  $myList');

  await prefs.setStringList('myjsonlist', myListOfJsonStrings);

  List<String> myjsonList = (prefs.getStringList('myjsonlist') ?? List<String>()) ;
  print('Your list  $myjsonList');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a string, you can store it

```
import 'dart:convert';
...
var s = json.encode(myMap);
// or var s = jsonEncode(myMap);

json.decode()/jsonDecode() makes a map from a string when you load it.
```