# How could i do to save Future<dynamic> with SharePreferences in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list from json decode. i want to save in local or sharepreferences in flutter.

It can be happen or theres another way ?

Here my code. I want to save temporaryData in sharepreferences.

```
_getTemp() async {
Map bodyFill = {'data': '$dataApi'};
DateTime start = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(seconds: 5));
DateTime end = DateTime.now();
Map data = {'pass': '123456', 'startTime': '$start', 'endTime': '$end'};
var response = await http.post('$urlApiQr:8080/newFindRecords', body: data);
var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
TempJson tempJson = TempJson.fromJson(jsonData);
var parse = json.decode(tempJson.config);

setState(() {
  dataList = parse;
  temporaryData = dataList.toSet().toList();
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since [Chetan Suri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13288749/chetan-suri) has given an answer, but would like to give out more vivid response on how you can achieve via your method's call.

**IMPORTANT:** Use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#-changelog-tab-) flutter package, if you don't know about it already.

So in order to make a method, you must pass the arguments, pass `temporaryData` and you should be fine.

```
// Here you create your sharepref instance to be used for further uses
Future<SharedPreferences> storage(){
  return SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}

// Here where you save your data which accepts a dynamic list arguments
void setTempData(List<String> temp) async{
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = await storage();
  sharedPref.setStringList("temp_list", temp);
}
```

Now from the method `_getTemp` save it into the `SharedPreferences` via the above method. **Make sure that you make the tempData String before you pass, cos SharedPreferences cannot store the Dynamic List till now**

```
setState(() {
  dataList = parse;
  temporaryData = dataList.toSet().toList();

  //type casting the temporaryData before passing it to the SharePref, else you will get type mismatch error
  setTempData(temporaryData.toString());
});
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yeah, my bad, did not take a look at that. Thanks for picking this up :) Correcting it

Comment: i try to get it but there error Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>' and when i set temporaryData.toString() show red underline, The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>'.

Comment: Can you try, passing just `temporaryData` without doing `temporaryData.toString()` and let me know?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Comment: Convert your `temporaryData` from `List<dynamic>` to `List<String>` like this: `var data = List<String>.from(temporaryData);` and then pass it into the `setTempData(data)`. Let me know if that works for you :)

Comment: another error, Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' :')

Comment: Hey @elhamyudhistira, I guess this would work. Pass the variable `jsonData` into your `setTempData(jsonData)`. No need of passing the `temporaryData`, since `json.encode(response.body)` will turn your map into string. And then in the main method `setTempData`, do this, `setString('temp_data', temp);`. Please note, do `setString()` not `setStringList()`. Let me know if that works out for you

Comment: its work but only show Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'

Comment: To get the data from your shared pref, you need to get it via `json.decode(...)`/`jsonDecode(...)` @elhamyudhistira. Else, you will see this only `instance of Future<Dynamic>`.

Comment: when i use json.decode/jsonDecode, theres error Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: Do some research @elhamyudhistira. Take some help from the information you have with this answer, and the conversation we have had. I hope with some efforts you will be able to get what you want :) Follow this link, I guess this might help you a bit => https://stackoverflow.com/a/48117264/5362583

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this.

```
  SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                    await _prefs.setString('pass', result['pass']);
                    await _prefs.setInt('startTime', result['startTime']);
                    await _prefs.setInt('endTime', result['endTime']);
```

Comment: i did it but i get value is Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'