# Saving a map containg a list into a database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a way to convert a `Map<int, List<int>>` object to string (and vice versa) to be able to save it to my database using sqflite.

```dart
class ClassToBeSavedInDB {
  final String name;
  final Map<int, List<int>> listByIDs;
  ClassToBeSavedInDB({this.name, this.listByIDs});
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'listByIDs': listByIDs, // TODO: convert this to a String
    };
  }
}
```

I tried to use `json.encode(map)` as suggested in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48117264/14887073) but I've got the following exception:

```
: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'JsLinkedHashMap<int, List<int>>'Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'JsLinkedHashMap<int, List<int>>'
```

**Update**

It looks like jsonDecode didn't like the int keys. Using `Map<String, List<int>>` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your map to JSON and put it to a DB as string.

Answer (score 0):

We first need to convert that object to something that could be possible to convert into json string.

In this case instead of just using jsonEncode(listByIDs) , you can first parse the map to string so that it becomes valid to be converted to json.

Hence do this : jsonEncode(listByIDs.toString()) ..... This will solve the issue.

EDIT :

Sorry for the initial answer. So the correct answer will be to use a callback called toEncodable.
Below is the answer:

```
jsonEncode(map,toEncodable: (val){print("Encoded value : $val");return 1;});
```

Comment: By doing this, jsonDecode will return a String instead of Map when reading the values from the db.

Comment: @Marwén I have posted the correct way in the solution. Do check it out